# Pattern recognition / Data classification

Tags: design-patterns, multiclass-classification

I am developing a project in which I must analyze a considerable amount of data. It is a monitoring system in **real time**, which is applied to electrical equipment.

The situation is this: In an imaginary scenario, I will have a vector such as:

[1.4, 5.1, 23.3, 4.5, 12.5, 6.1, .....] (With a size of N values)

I must establish 3 types of "classifications" which could be:

1) If several "1.5" are found in the vector, then do event A.

2) If several "5" are found in the vector,  then do event B.

3) If several "15" are found in the vector,  then do event C.

Practically what must be done is to analyze the information that receives and according to it perform different events.

Which technique should I use Pattern recognition, Data classification, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a modified visitor pattern.

```
foreach(var elem in elements)
{
    foreach (var visitor in visitors)
    {
        //more clear than having a method called Visit
        if (visitor.CanTransition(elem))
        {
            var eventToDo = visitor.getNewEvent();
        }
    }
}
```